# read lines from file(string:value) and write to lines with value > 4000 to new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

current code:

```
f1 = open("input.txt",'r')
f2 = open("output.txt",'w')
for i in f1.readlines():
    parts = i.split(":")

    if parts[2] > 4000 :
        f2.write(i)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Hi I have been trying but I cannot get my code to work, would be amazing to see how this problem of mine could be written. Basically I have a test file containing a string, delimeter(:) and a value.
Example:

```
maxwalker2004:0
maxterix:564
maxxorclank8:1313
maxxie100:0
maxxman390:45
maxxor51:0
maxy234567890:20
maxxy35:0
maxyboy2010:0
maxydupo:297
maxyoops57:748
maxy088:0
maxychamp9:132
maxymillio:0
mayapooh514:0
mayelistar:0
mayer48:425
mayasissy461:0
mayowastar:0
mays12345:332
mayna2cute:0
mayyah3:0
mazefire3609:4088
mbjewett:0
mbbvcac77:0
mbakkertje:0
mbieber11:0
mbiles:5497
mbomb56:797
mcadamslance:0
mcake123:0
mcarlin99:486
mburnsb1:0
mcash225:0
mb1005263:0
mazi23:5497
mbz360:0
mccayleigh:0
mccoyzachary21:0
mcbloom8:259
mcd2315:0
mcdude22:1305
mccurdy03:8275
mcdino13:0
mcdudu45:355
mcethan25:0
mcfootball10:26130
```

These lines are being read from .txt `file1`. I want all lines with a value (string:value) above 4000 to be written to second output file`(file2)` 
and rest being ignored.

Not sure but can't get it to work... 
Thanks, appreciate

Comment: Show some code you've tried with in the first place, then we will start from there

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: post the code that you can't get to work

Comment: Ok. updated post :)

Comment: You should replace `parts[2]` with `parts[1]`, since Python indexes from 0.

Comment: oh haha. changed that. I do however get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` I am struggling to work with two different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if it works by this condition:

```
if int(parts[1]) > 4000 :
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = open("file1", 'r')  # Opening file1
f2 = open("file2", 'w')  # Opening file2
for i in f1.readlines():  # Iterating through file1 line by line
    if int(i.split(':')[-1]) > 4000:  # Splitting the string by ':'
        f2.write(i)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Try this

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' :(

Comment: sorry, just edited the code. forgot to access the value

Comment: Hm not sure what you did. pretty new to python. I do however get this error back: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Split at `:` only once, and verify that it is an integer before you try to make an `int`.

```
for line in f1.readlines():
    key, value = line.split(':', 1)
    if value.isdigit() and int(value) > 4000:
        f2.write(line + '\n')
```

Or with context managers:

```
with open('file1', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('file2', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file.readlines():
            key, value = line.split(':', 1)
            if value.isdigit() and int(value) > 4000:
                out_file.write(line + '\n')
```